# Displaying progress dialog before show content

Tags: android, multithreading

```
     progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
     Thread thread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            latch.countDown();
            try{
                sleep(3000);        
                } 
            catch (Exception e) {       
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());       
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    };
    thread.start();   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want show loading in 3 seconds then show listview but list always show immediately. How can I want thread finished before showing listview?

Comment: don't force your users to needlessly wait for 3 seconds. You are just wasting their time. if you have loading work to do, do it in the background properly with an AsyncTask, and show them the result as soon as its ready. There is no good reason for you to waste 3 seconds of their time...

Comment: Thank you. I knew this but I have a reason for this situation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't make people wait for no reason. If you have something to load, load it. Otherwise draw what you can when you can.

As an answer to your specific question you would need to have the Thread `setAdapter` after it slept for 3 seconds (right now that call is outside the Thread... I think you think that that call blocks, but that's the whole point of the Thread, it does its own thing while the rest of your code executes).

However, Thread can't do anything to your display thread (other than throw an exception) so you'd have to wrap that `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` call in a `Runnable` and call it via a `Handler` from your Thread....

but don't!

Comment: Yes, you are right. We shouldn't make people wait for nothing. But I have reason to do with this :-)

Comment: It works with Handler. Many thanks Dr. Dredel. You save my day :-)